# byte array in groovy

Tags: java, groovy, arrays

in java I can create byte array: `byte[] array = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };`
but this construct is invalid in groovy. How I can create byte array in groovy ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The following should suffice:

```
def array = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] as byte[]
```

Have a look [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/JN1025-Arrays) for more details on arrays in groovy.

Answer (score 19):

In addition to [rich.okelly's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10012581/6509),

```
byte[] array = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

works as well

Answer (score 5):

You can't initialize a literal array the same way because Groovy thinks the curly brackets form a closure. What you want is something like

```
def x = [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] as byte[]
```

See more: [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/FAQ+-+Collections,+Lists,+etc.)